# SQL Trim Preceding zeros

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an ID that looks like below:

```
000000000000000091
000000000000000019
000000000000001859
000000000000001220
000000000000001220
000000000000001182
000000000000010156
```

I am looking to trim the preceeding zero's so only yhe

I need to trim the values so it shows up like below:

```
91
19
1859
1220
1220
1182
10156
```

I am trying to do the following:

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET Material = RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(Material,'0',' '))),' ','0'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Substring with PatIndex without any conversion.

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET Material = Substring(Material, PatIndex('%[1-9]%',Material),Len(Material))
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try casting it to int or bigint?

Something like

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET Material = CAST(Material AS BIGINT)
```

For your input

```
WITH DATA AS
(
    SELECT Material
    FROM
    (
        VALUES('000000000000000091'),
            ('000000000000000019'),
            ('000000000000001859'),
            ('000000000000001220'),
            ('000000000000001220'),
            ('000000000000001182'),
            ('000000000000010156')
    ) Data (Material)
)
SELECT Material, CAST(Material AS BIGINT) AS Material_Output
FROM Data
```

Answer (score 1):

If the numbers are integers below the 2^63 mark you can use `CAST()`. For example:

```
with
t as (
  select '000000000000000091' as v
  union all select '000000000000000019'
  union all select '000000000000001859'
  union all select '000000000000001220'
  union all select '000000000000001220'
  union all select '000000000000001182'
  union all select '000000000000010156'
)
select '' + cast(v as bigint) from t
```

Result:

```
 (No column name) 
 ---------------- 
 91               
 19               
 1859             
 1220             
 1220             
 1182             
 10156
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=65a4d99d01459ba51f812ac03bcfb23e).

Comment: The table contains thousands of materials. I was hoping to have something that will convert them all to an int. I could also add another feild called MaterialINT

Comment: @HarshBilodiya Yes, casting will do the trick, but you'll need to create an extra column for the int values, at least temporarily.

Comment: you are correct. I was able to do using the temp column. Thank you!